# Handling Home button in android?

Tags: android, events, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can i override HOME Button on my own Home-Screen from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547818/can-i-override-home-button-on-my-own-home-screen-from-my-application)

How can I handle the Home button click in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home button is reserved for the OS as a "last chance" escape for the user from any app. Developers cannot override it, this way ensuring that the user will always have the possibility to leave the app.

Comment: I think that's the power button, the home button can be overridden like in Lucasneo's answer

Comment: this is definitely note true. When you create a type_system_alert view, home button cannot work anymore. Refer to here fore more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750814/creating-a-system-overlay-where-the-home-buttons-still-work