# method to call when home button clicked?

Tags: android, android-activity

In My android application, currently one of my activity is focused on the screen. If the user clicked on "HOME" button, which activity method gets invoked.

Comment: "Home button is reserved for the OS as a "last chance" escape for the user from any app. Developers cannot override it, this way ensuring that the user will always have the possibility to leave the app." -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226001/handling-home-button-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override anything about the Home activity. You can only use the [Home intent category.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#iobjs)

See this other question for more info:

[Can I override the 'Home' button in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547818/can-i-override-home-button-on-my-own-home-screen-from-my-application)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to handle "Home" button click. And this is by design.

Read great post by CommonsWare: [Please Ignore the HOME Button](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/08/please-ignore-home-button.html). Also see [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b6b448f7df87b334) and [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/0bb52d77ba595525) threads on Android Developers group.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me..

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
}
```

Then

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){
        // Your code here.
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Works for me on Android 2.3. However it seems to be a hack rather then intended use of API and does not work for me on Android 4.