# How do I implement a slide-out drawer on the Android's call screen?

Tags: android, sliding, drawer

The Android app Thrutu puts a drawer on top of the in call screen which has several functions and only takes up a fraction of the screen. The call control buttons below still are fully functional. Even a transparent activity would not allow this behaviour. Any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: I am also looking for same thing . Let me know if you found out .

Answer (score 5):

The trick to making the underlying buttons work is to implement the UI using a Service rather than an Activity, make the Window you add (using WindowManager.addView) one of the higher-priority types (e.g. TYPE_PHONE), then use FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL.

I *think* you need android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW.

Take a look at [How to display a fullscreen TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371432/how-to-display-a-fullscreen-type-system-alert-window) and in particular [Creating a system overlay where the home buttons still work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750814/creating-a-system-overlay-where-the-home-buttons-still-work)