# Show Caller Location On Incoming Screen

Tags: android

I am developing an app which the Location of Caller on Incoming call Screen.

To show that I used Toast, But I came to about ann App which does this but not using Toast.

It uses something else to show something on Incoming Call Screen.  I want to know what is that control.

The screen shot is attached here

[image]

As you can see in the image. I want to know about the control or View (that is in red Line Center).

This particular contriol can be dragged up and down and can be  closed on clicking cross button

How to create this control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use system overlays to put a view on top of all the screens..

check out following post for more info:

[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android)

[Creating a system overlay where the home buttons still work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750814/creating-a-system-overlay-where-the-home-buttons-still-work)

[AirCalc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myboyfriendisageek.aircalc&hl=en) is one more proof of concept...

Comment: @kamal : I understand this Overlay concept. Can u please tell me How did you find the location when call is coming ?